# List the most recently hired employee in each department

Tags: sql

I'am a trainee in sql, any help for this query,would be great.TIA.

```
    select distinct jobtitle,max([HireDate]),LoginID from [HumanResources].[Employee] as e 
where loginid in (select distinct LoginID from HumanResources.Employee 
                where JobTitle in (select distinct JobTitle from [HumanResources].[Employee]) )
group by JobTitle,LoginID;
```

Comment: Have you tried doing anything for yourself yet?

Comment: I have just started learning ruby.And it'll be good if you can suggest any good tutorials.

Comment: Try this - http://bit.ly/1gDXoAt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about a command line program this will work.

```
puts "Hello World"
```

or if you want an object oriented version

```
class HelloWorld
   def initialize(name)
      @name = name.capitalize
   end
   def sayHi
      puts "Hello #{@name}!"
   end
end

hello = HelloWorld.new("World")
hello.sayHi
```

If you are looking for a ruby on rails version of Hello World. Check the Getting Started [Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#hello-rails) for Rails.